# Return type of swift code

Tags: swift, return-type

i created a function which returns multiple values.

However further up in my code i would like to catch these values in a `var`.
How do i declare this `var` in my class? i need to know what is exactly returned and of which type it is.

Also i would appreciate it very much if you could explain why, and how to figure it out myself.

here is my a part of my code:

```
 func returnTypes(value: Int) -> (international:String, europe: Int, us: Int, ru: Int){
    if value >= 86 && value <= 118{
        switch value{
        case 88:
            return ("XXS",28, 28, 42)
        case 90:
            return ("XS",29, 29, 44)
        case 92:
            return ("S",30, 30 ,46)
        default:
            return ("XXS", 28,28,42)
        }
    }
}
```

this is where i want to grab the results:

```
if gender == NSLocalizedString("GENDER_MALE",comment: "COMMENT"){
          returned = converter.returnTypes(NSDEFAULTMETHOD.toInt()!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note this is not multiple return values but rather a tuple which is returning one object that contains multiple values. To access them in a variable, the variable needs to be a tuple of the same type (which is the return type of your function). Also, you need to return something in your function outside your if-statement.

```
func returnTypes(value: Int) -> (international:String, europe: Int, us: Int, ru: Int) {
    if value >= 86 && value <= 118{
        switch value{
        case 88:
            return ("XXS",28, 28, 42)
        case 90:
            return ("XS",29, 29, 44)
        case 92:
            return ("S",30, 30 ,46)
        default:
            return ("XXS", 28,28,42)
        }
    }
    return ("",0,0,0)
}

var tuple: (international:String, europe: Int, us: Int, ru: Int) = returnTypes(5)
```

And to access the values:

```
tuple.europe
tuple.international
tuple.ru
tuple.us
```